# How to use namespace JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, namespaces

Hi I am trying to call the namespace JavaScript which is given in the internal JavaScript in below HTML representation.

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var ns = {
            sampleAlert : function() {
                ns.message(var );
            }

            message :function(var ) {
                alert('msg');
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <!--how to call the function sampleAlert-->
</body>
```

Is that possible? I am not able to call that namespace JavaScript function  in the body.

Comment: That code may be throwing you an error because "var" is not defined in "sampleAlert".

Comment: It's also missing a comma between the two functions.

Comment: could you give the sample code for statement .. <!--how to call the function sampleAlert--> in the body

Answer (score 0):

Call it like this:

```
ns.sampleAlert();
```

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881515/how-do-i-declare-a-namespace-in-javascript) link to have more understanding on JavaScript Namespace

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to do something like the following.

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var ns = {
            sampleAlert : function(messageText) {
                ns.message(messageText);
            },

            message : function(text) {
                alert('msg ' + text);
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <!--how to call the function sampleAlert-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        ns.sampleAlert("this text will be displayed in the alert");
    </script>
</body>
```